# main loop 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Tags: python, built-in, iterable

I get this error "main loop 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable" when I run the code below:

I have search stackoverflow, but cant find a answer to my question...

I have checked for typos, but cant find any error. Please help me!

```
import urllib2
import time
import datetime

stocksToPull = 'AAPL','GOOG','MSFT','CMG','AMZN','EBAY','TSLA'

def pullData(stock):
    try:
        print 'Currently pulling',stock
        print str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
        urlToVisit = 'http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/'+stock+'/chartdata;type=quote;range=5d/csv'
        saveFileLine = stock+'.txt'

        try:
            readExistingData = open(saveFileLine,'r').read()
            splitExisting = readExistingData.split('\n')
            mostRecentLine = splitExisting[-2]
            lastUnix = mostRecentLine.split(',')[0]
        except:
            lastUnix = 0

        saveFile = open(saveFileLine,'a')
        sourceCode = urllib2.urlopen(urlToVisit).read()
        splitSource = sourceCode.split

        for eachLine in splitSource:
            splitLine = eachLine.split(',')
            if len(splitLine) ==6:
                if splitLine[0] > lastUnix:
                    if 'values' not in eachLine:
                        lineToWrite = eachLine+'\n'
                        saveFile.write(lineToWrite)

        saveFile.close()

        print 'Pulled',stock
        print 'sleeping...'
        print str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
        time.sleep(300)

    except Exception,e:
        print 'main loop',str(e)

for eachStock in stocksToPull:
    pullData(eachStock)
```

Comment: You might need to add a language tag so that it shows up in the proper community - you'll get more attention that way.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Direct Answer**

In the code here:

```
saveFile = open(saveFileLine,'a')
sourceCode = urllib2.urlopen(urlToVisit).read()
splitSource = sourceCode.split
```

change `sourceCode.split` to `sourceCode.split()`.

---

**If you want to know more about this error, read below:**

When debugging, you'd better remove the try...except block, especially an "expect Exception" block, which is so generic that you will get lost about what is going wrong.

When removed the try...except block and run these code again, you will get error info like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-c4fe20f718cd> in <module>()
     43 
     44 for eachStock in stocksToPull:
---> 45     pullData(eachStock)

<ipython-input-5-c4fe20f718cd> in pullData(stock)
     23     splitSource = sourceCode.split
     24 
---> 25     for eachLine in splitSource:
     26         splitLine = eachLine.split(',')
     27         if len(splitLine) ==6:

TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

The error message `TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable` is associated with line 25, which means `splitSource` is a `builtin_function_or_method` and is not `iterable`.

What is `splitSource`? It is `sourceCode.split`. Here comes the answer. You should call a method by using `()`, without which you will get the method itself. The method `str.split` is obviously not `iterable`!

Comment: Thanks! That made it work:   splitSource = sourceCode.split('\n')

Comment: Cool. Could you please mark this reply as *Answer* if you think it is helpful?